# Slow query results transfer from MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two virtual servers in cloud: DB and Web. There is MS SQL Server Express 2012 instance on Db server. In Database in SQL Server there is the table 'Job' with relatively big records(10Kb per record).

When i run simple query from DB server, it takes less than one second to execute. But when i run it from Web server it takes more than one minute.

```
SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM Job
```

And it have direct relationship between retrived records count and time to execute. It takes about seven minutes to retrieve 100000 records from Web server.

In SQL Server Profiles it takes same CPU time to execute query from DB and Web server, but total time different.

The same effect is on any query which returns large amount of bytes.

I have another application servers in this cloud and they have that effect too.

But on development environment and other deploys all is ok. Query executes on Web server slightly slow than on DB Server.

I have checked network speed between Web and DB servers. Its stable and about 1Gb. Turning off Windows Firewall have no effect.

Comment: There are some speed bumps in the engine when it comes to transferring very broad rows. See what happens if you specify `Packet Size=32767` in your connection string (this is the maximum allowed).

Comment: It works. Thank you. Now it takes about ten seconds to retrive 10000 records. 10000 * 10Kb = ~100Mb. I think it's normal for 1Gb network.But why i don't have this problem on another deploys? I don't have this parameter in connection string there.

Comment: There is likely some interaction between the default TDS packet size (4000 bytes or 4096 bytes, depending on the client) and the packet size of your network, where one case leads to excessive packet fragmentation and the other does not. While I know of the issue and the most likely fix, I've never delved deeply into the precise mechanism. All I do know is that the TDS network library can get into some pathological corner cases and that this most often happens if rows are broader than will fit in a single TDS packet.